# Cross push notifications from Qt to iOS & Android with V-Play (Felgo) and google cloud message (firebase)

Tags: qt, qml, firebase-cloud-messaging, cross-platform, v-play

I try to create a push notifications project that send to iOS and Android concurrently in the same moment.

I'm going to try V-Play plugin: https://v-play.net/doc/plugin-gcm/
but from guide, I can't find how to set Google Cloud Messaging in Firebase.

There is a tutorial that step by step permit to configure and try the cross platform notifications? Or could anyone see how to set the code correctly?
Also I saw OneSignal, is it better then GCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OneSignal is one of the most used push notification services now and a great solution. You can find an integration guide with step-by-step instructions and example code to make it work with Qt & QML here:
https://v-play.net/doc/plugin-onesignal/

The push notifications are available in the Firebase Qt Plugin: https://v-play.net/doc/plugin-firebase/

Comment: Reading the documentation this seems like the perfect solution!!, but forgive my simple question (newbie here), how would I 'send', or tirigger a notification to be sent when for example an `AppButton.OnClicked` signal is sent?

Comment: Hi @Ldweller, you can trigger a local notification when clicking a button. In general, push notifications are sent by a server. You can head over to the Felgo support forums to ask any other questions: https://felgo.com/developers/forums/